# I stopped game sharing with a friend on PS4,can i still get banned?

Tags: ps4

I was game sharing with a friend on ps4 but i stopped because a lot of people were saying that it was against their TOS and now i'm very worried that i still could be banned :(

Comment: What does "game sharing" mean exactly?

Comment: When i activate my account as primary on a friend's PS4 so he can download all of my games and i do the same with his account

Comment: If it was illegal, you wouldn't be able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing your games by setting your friend console as [primary](https://www.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/How_to_Game-Share_with_Family_and_Friends) is not against Sony/SIE's [Terms of Service](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/network/legal/terms-of-service/):

> However, some content and features that are made available for certain subscriptions may be accessible by other users of the Authorized Device¹ of a subscriber or an Authorized Device where a subscriber is logged in.

¹ Your friend's PS4 is the authorized device in this case.

Comment: So it it's not illegal?because a LOT of people say it is

Comment: Is not illegal.

Comment: @GarfieldLynns: Breaking Terms of Service in general is not illegal.  It may get you banned, but it's not going to get you arrested _(unless you do something actually illegal)_

Comment: Okay cool,but what i wanna know is can i get banned because of it?